# Variables in append

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

I want to insert variable number into an append to make lists with variable img file. I have this code:

```
<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>

var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

This make variable form inputs with the counter variable, but i want to make this with a

```
<li>, check this:

 <ul class="popupimg">
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img1.png" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img1.png" alt="Img1" title="Img1"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img2.png" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img2.png" alt="Img2" title="Img2"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img3.png" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img3.png" alt="Img3" title="Img3"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img4.jpg" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img4.jpg" alt="Img4" title="Img4"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img5.jpg" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img5.jpg" alt="Img5" title="Img5"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Imagenes/img6.jpg" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img6.jpg" alt="Img6" title="Img6"></a></li>

                    </ul>
```

Adding the li and the img with variable number, instead 3 or 4, a counter number for each click.

How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery when it is pure JavaScript? jQuery would allow for much simpler code if you allow it. Do you want jQuery or Javascript or you don't care (so long as it works)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind jQuery (my preference), the following demonstrates using a dummy `script` element (with unknown type) to hold a template for new items (much nicer than in-line strings in the code):

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <li><a href="Imagenes/img{n}.png" class="image-link"><img src="Imagenes/img{n}.png" alt="Img{n}" title="Img{n}"/></a></li>
</script>
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vs6K9/1/

```
    var $images = $('#Images');
    var template = $('#template').html();
    template = template.replace(/\{n\}/g, counter);
    $images.append(template);
```

The code just replaces the {n} marker with your new value then appends the template. It uses a regular expression with the `g` global flag as `replace` normally replaces only the first match.

I just appended the images to a new div and left your existing code in place.

Based on the comment, if you want the image numbers to start at say 6, use this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vs6K9/26/

```
    var $images = $('#Images');
    var template = $('#template').html();
    template = template.replace(/\{n\}/g, $images.children().length +6);
    $images.append(template);
```

*Note: also now made the images list a UL instead of DIV (my bad)* :)

Comment: Thanks, but how can begin to count to 6 instead 1? For example, click and count img6, img7... not begin in img1.

Comment: It's just a number, currently using the `counter` value. Try `template = template.replace(/\{n\}/g, $images.children().length +6);` This will use the number of images already there, starting first one at 6.

Comment: Okay, and how can do the same but with h3 and <p>? And not by variable, instead of this i want that the first h3 and p have a title apple and the p has this is a fruit, and in the second click add another h3 and p, in this  the first h3 have a title oranges, and the p has "this is an orange", and so on... How can i do this?

Comment: Add multiple placeholders to the template and one `replace` per unique placeholder. You really should ask another specific question :)

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to do this exactly... :( I'm a newbie with jquery

Comment: That's fine. Just ask another question rather than keep extending this one :) Thanks.

Comment: I asked another, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804947/create-different-text-blocks-with-a-click-button-on-hold